# How to set width and height for NavigationDrawer in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose

Right now I am using the `Scaffold()` composable to create a basic drawer layout. However the drawer is always the same size but I want it with a custom width, taking only 2/3 of the screen size and also a custom height, like a padding top and bottom. This is my code so far:

```
Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = state,
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = {
                                    SearchBar()
                                    },
                            navigationIcon = {
                                IconButton(onClick = {
                                    coroutineScope.launch { state.drawerState.open() }
                                }) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = null)
                                }
                            },
                            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                        )
                    },
                    drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 16.dp, bottomEnd = 16.dp),
                    drawerContent = { NavigationDrawer(state, coroutineScope) },
                    content = {
                        MapScreen(
                        )
                    }
                )
```

Changing anything in my composable function `NavigationDrawer()` won't change anything. Is there any way to achieve this in jetpack compose?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a private val in Drawer which is the problem `EndDrawerPadding = 56.dp`

On tablets you would want a much larger amount of padding.

Since this can't be changed the best solution I could come up with was to make the drawer background transparent with no shadow, then in content set a smaller view, with a shape and shadow.

```
     Scaffold(
                topBar = { TopAppBarTablet(){
                    scope.launch { drawerState.open() }
                } },
                drawerBackgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.transparent),
                drawerElevation = 0.dp,
                drawerContent = {
                    Surface(
                        Modifier
                            .width(300.dp).fillMaxHeight(),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.positive),
                        elevation = 4.dp
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_home),
                            modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = colorResource(R.color.negative)
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
```

Answer (score -3):

You can add something like this.

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldWithPanel() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { ... },
        bottomBar = { ... },
        bodyContent = {
            WithConstraints {
                val parentWidth = with(AmbientDensity.current) {
                    constraints.maxWidth.toDp()
                }
                val parentHeight = with(AmbientDensity.current) {
                    constraints.maxHeight.toDp() 
                }
                Box {
                    MainContent()
                    if(drawerState.value != DrawerValue.Open) {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(parentWidth / 2, height = parentHeight)) {
                            SidePanel()   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

For more detail visit this website:
https://amryousef.me/side-drawer-jetpack-compose

Comment: Did you try your answer with a beta version? Most of properties and Composables were renamed.

Comment: Did you look into the doc I attached? I did not test all its just the logic to show how to set the hight and width,